# Error connecting to SQL Server in AspNetCore applications

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, web-applications, entity-framework-core

I'm facing an "annoying" problem... Any project that I start in Visual Studio or VSCode and try to connect to the SQL Server database running via Docker, the error below occurs:

[Error in SQL connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC2R6.png)

Even pointing to the context file, the connection always tries to the user in the print above

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
public DbSet<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
public DbSet<Pedido> Pedidos { get; set; }
public DbSet<PedidoItem> PedidoItems { get; set; }
public DbSet<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost,1433;Database=DbPedidos;User Id=sa;Password=1q2w3e4r@#$;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=True");
}
```

What can it be?

I've done everything as described above, I've uninstalled SQL Server LocalDb 2019 from the machine, I've deleted the local database file and several other things, but nothing works.

Comment: Do not expose your username and password on this site. Please edit.

Comment: `Trusted_Connection=True` why is that there? And `Integrated Security=True` is a synonym of the same, and also shouldn't be there.

Comment: Brows, sorry, I changed "Integrated Security" to "False" and everything worked perfectly! "Trusted_Connection" is "True" because the certificates are valid.
@Alex, user ID, passwords and database name are fictitious.
Thank you all for your help!